# How I can search where is my module situated from URL?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a URL and I would like found where is module situated. 
For example `index.php/agentdeposit/adminhtml_order/finalize/order_id/`. How I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is comprised of 3 primary components:

```
agentdeposit/adminhtml_order/finalize/order_id/
    |            |              |
    | Module     |              |
                 | Controller   |
                                | Action
```

Where:

- Module is an alias to the real module, defined by a `<frontName>` XML node.
- Controller is a path partial to the real controller class.
- Action is the method name partial in the controller class.

And the route translates to file path, something like this:

- `app/code/local/Agentdeposit/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php`

To find exactly the owning module, you can use `grep`:

```
grep -rn '<frontName>agentdeposit' /path/to/magento/app/code
```

This should turn up 1 result, a reference to a `config.xml` file. This will give you the answer you're looking for.

I also notice that the URL you posted is using pre-SUPEE-6788 syntax, which has since been deprecated and disabled under most newer shops for security reasons. Magento now recommends a different syntax for declaring admin routes. Some additional reading on the subject:

> https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Comment: thank you very much for an understandable and complete answer)

Comment: and for, example, /checkout/onepage/?

Comment: You're welcome. For the checkout, solution is the same: use `grep`. In this case we know that `checkout` is part of the core `Mage_Checkout` module. But you must also be aware of controller overloading/rewrites, where an extending module can take control of any route. Learn more [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-overriding-in-magento-controllers--cms-23386). If you suspect another module is overriding the checkout, you can use `grep -rn 'before="Mage_Checkout"' app/code`.