# Create link to new page.

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to create link to new page.

```
 <?php if ($model->_data['firstname'].' '.$model->_data['lastname']===$managedAgents[$orderItem->getAgentId()]) :?>
 <?php if($orderItem->qty_invoiced==0):?>
<a href="">
  <?php echo $this->__('Finalize Order')?>
 </a>
<?php else:?>
<?php echo $this->__('Payment made'); ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Which way do I need to write in href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not force you to use a specific URL generation function. You could enter `/module/controller/action` and get away with it. However, you *should* use the built-in method `$this->getUrl()`, which is available to every template you will edit in a Magento theme.

Some background:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php, lines ~994-1004
/**
 * Generate url by route and parameters
 *
 * @param   string $route
 * @param   array $params
 * @return  string
 */
public function getUrl($route = '', $params = array())
{
    return $this->_getUrlModel()->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

- Every template is assigned to a block class.
- Every block class [should] inherit from the abstract.
- Therefore, `getUrl` is a universal method for generating valid Magento URLs.

Your question is not clear, but knowing that you asked a question about something [similar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/206946/1834) already today, I can take a guess at what you're looking for:

```
...
<?php if ($orderItem->qty_invoiced == 0) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('agentdeposit/adminhtml_order/finalize', array('order_id' => $orderItem->getOrderId())); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->__('Finalize Order'); ?>
</a>
<?php else : ?>
...
```

- Route: `agentdeposit/adminhtml_order/finalize`
- Parameters: `array('order_id' => $orderItem->getOrderId()))`

Your order ID property might be something else, I'm not sure.